# Matplotlib: axvline not orientated on .axis but on ylim

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure with two plots next to each other, like this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 2), (0, 0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 2), (0, 1))
```

Now i want to plot a vertical line into the first subplot. Therfore, I use

```
ax1.axvline(x, ymin=0.25, ymax=0.5, color='k')
```

However, the problem is that now ymin and ymax are used with respect to the axis, where 0 would be the bottom and 1 the to of the plot. But I want to use with respect to the y-axis of the plot, which is from -1 to 1. If I instead use

```
plt.axvline(x, ymin=0.25, ymax=0.5, color='k')
```

the vertical lines are drawn in the second plot. Is there any possibility besides calculating ratios like

```
ymin_plot1 = -1
ymax_plot1 = 1
ymin_vert_line = (0.25 - ymin_plot1)/(ymax_plot1 - ymin_plot1)
ymin_vert_line = (0.5 - ymin_plot1)/(ymax_plot1 - ymin_plot1)
```

to solve that problem?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ax.axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html) is hardcoded to use its own transform, and the y coordinates are therefore always plotted with respect to the axes coordinates, not the data coordinates. From the docs:

> `ymin` float, default: 0
>
> Should be between 0 and 1, 0 being the bottom of the plot, 1 the top of the plot.

There are alternatives, however. For example, [`ax.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines) allows you to specify the `ymin` and `ymax` in relation to the data rather than the axes.

So, you would just need to change your call to `axvline` to one using `vlines`:

```
ax1.vlines(x, ymin=0.25, ymax=0.5, color='k')
```